# while true x loop do

Tags: ruby, loop, while

Desenvolvendo alguns scripts em Ruby me deparo com a seguinte situação:

Há de fato várias Estruturas de Repetição, mas 2 em particular me chamaram a atenção. `while true` e `loop do`. Ambas geram o que todos conhecem como ***"looping infinito"***. Mas, existe algo que torne uma mais performática que a outra!?

No caso do `loop do` ele executará a ação infinitamente ou até eu estabelecer (se estabelecer) um condição de parada. Ex:

```
count = 1
loop do 
  puts count
  count += 1
end
```

Porém levando essa lógica para o `while true` temos implicitamente a explicativa ***"ele executará enquanto a condição for verdadeira"***, mas que condição!? Ex:

```
count = 1
while true 
  puts count
  count += 1
end
```

Além da questão da sintaxe, existe algo que os diferencie no sentido de performance ou pode haver algo no meu código que possa vir a dar problema em um dos 2 laços (talvez esse 'true' no while)?

Quando devo usar cada um deles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Ruby é uma linguagem que possibilita maneiras diferentes para o mesmo fim. O intuito é aumentar a semântica do código, deixando-o mais legível. No caso citado, é um loop infinito.

A diferença entre as construções `while` e `loop` no Ruby é que o `while` aceita uma condição. Essa condição é posta logo após a keyword. Veja:

```
while tem_internet? # <<< condição é tem_internet?
  navegar 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/'
end
```

Assim que `tem_internet?` for *evaluado* para `false`, o laço vai parar. O equivalente do código acima com uma construção `loop` seria:

```
loop do
  break unless tem_internet?
  navegar 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/'
end
```

No caso do `while true`, a condição é sempre `true` e por isso é infinito.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, não utilizo ruby mas acredito que não á diferenças de performance entre laços de repetição, claro que isso varia de linguagem para linguagem. O `While (true)` vai executar infinitamente já `loop do` **acredito que seja um** `Do While()` ou seja ele vai executar ao menos uma vez o loop antes de verificar a condição de parada.

Quanto ao loop acredito que sua aplicação ira travar se tiver interface obviamente, pois a `thread` que contenha o loop infinito vai consumir todo o processamento. Se seu programa for de console não tem problemas porem deve ser intersecante colocar algum tipo de `sleep` para que ele não consuma muito de sua CPU.

Micro controladores funcionam com laço `While(true)` por exemplo utilizando 100% do processamento.